# Running inkscape without X server

Tags: process, xserver, inkscape

I am running `inkscape` from a Gearman PHP process on *nix-like systems (OS X 10.6.8, Linux of varying flavours) to convert SVG images to either PNG or PDF. I use something like this (line breaks added here just for clarity):

```
/full/path/to/inkscape -z \
    --export-png=/path/to/output.png \
    --export-width=100 --export-height=100 \
    /path/to/input.svg
```

It works, but despite the -z flag ("Do not use X server") I get this in my console output (on OS X):

```
Setting Language: .UTF-8

(process:44699): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "/tmp/launch-WvcqRh/org.x:0".
```

This suggests to me that inkscape is loading more libraries than it needs to, and that it could be faster if it didn't try to connect to an X server. However, other than using the `-z/--without-gui` flag, I am not sure what to try. Performance on my dev machine is still sub-second (at least for trivial SVG files), but I'd like to clean this up if I can. Even if the best answer is just "suppress error output"!

Maybe if I turn off or reset a bash DISPLAY env var? I'm not at all familiar with X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you want to make your programs not find X at all, you can `unset DISPLAY` before launching the process.

You can also use Xvfb to "fake" an X server: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

You might also want to look at these tools:

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~cworth/svg2pdf/
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~cworth/svg2png/

Their source code is *really* small.

Comment: Thanks, I will give the `DISPLAY` thing a go, and will report back! If that doesn't yield results I'll try Xvfb, but I'll be running this system on a _very_ lowly VPS, so want to keep my extra software to a minimum.

Comment: Btw; I've tried `svg2pdf`, certainly on my Mac, and it doesn't seem to do a very good job of rendering an Inkscape SVG document - various font styles from a single family were all rendered as the default variant. (Maybe there's something I need to configure here, but `inkscape` just gets it spot on).

Comment: I've tried `DISPLAY='' inkscape --export-png=output.png input.svg` and also a bash script with `unset DISPLAY` and then the `inkscape` command, and neither suppress the 'Gtk-WARNING'. Like you, I was rather expecting that to work - bah!

Comment: I don't have time to check Xvrb at the moment, but I should think that would work (for which I award a tick). Again, thanks for your response. In the meantime I'll just suppress errors with `2>/dev/null`! :-)

Comment: If I `unset DISPLAY` I get three errors `CRITICAL` (`dbus_g_proxy_nw_for_name`...)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to suppress the output, while preserving the ability to respond to true errors, is to call Inkscape from Python.

```
import subprocess               # May want to use subprocess32 instead

cmd_list = [ '/full/path/to/inkscape', '-z', 
             '--export-png', '/path/to/output.png',
             '--export-width', 100,
             '--export-height', 100,
             '/path/to/input.svg' ]

# Invoke the command.  Divert output that normally goes to stdout or stderr.
p = subprocess.Popen( cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )

# Below, < out > and < err > are strings or < None >, derived from stdout and stderr.
out, err = p.communicate()      # Waits for process to terminate

# Maybe do something with stdout output that is in < out >
# Maybe do something with stderr output that is in < err >

if p.returncode:
    raise Exception( 'Inkscape error: ' + (err or '?')  )
```

On my Mac OS system, the crufty status messages (described by the original poster) end up in `err`.  Plus, for a particular job that I ran, there is additional messaging that ends up in `out`:

```
Background RRGGBBAA: ffffff00
Area 0:0:339:339 exported to 100 x 100 pixels (72.4584 dpi)
Bitmap saved as: /path/to/output.png
```

(The input svg file had a size of 339 by 339 pixels.)

Answer (score 0):

`(echo foo.ai --export-plain-svg foo.svg) | DISPLAY= inkscape --shell`

Comment: Hi there, thanks for this. Can you explain this to me further? I'm not an expert-level shell user, but I am confused by the `--export-plain-svg` argument to `echo`. Is the essence of your technique that the image data is piped to the `inkscape` command with a null `DISPLAY` env var?